# Problem on infinite cardinal number

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

If $e$ is an infinite cardinal number and $d$ is a cardinal number satisfing
$2 ≤ d ≤ 2^e$. I need to prove the following

$$d^e= 2^e$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

.

Comment: You should understand without too much difficulty that it reduces to the case $d = 2^e$.  Then you need to find a bijection between $(2^e)^e$ and $2^e$.

Comment: The crucial ingredient is Hessenberg's Theorem, i.e. for any uncountable, initial ordinal (which just means 'cardinal' in the presence of choice) $\kappa$ we have $\kappa \times \kappa \equiv \kappa$ (which can equivalently be written as $\kappa \cdot \kappa = \kappa$ in cardinal arithmetic). A proof of this fact can be found in most introductory set theory textbooks.

Answer (score 3):

$$2^e\le d^e\le 2^{e\cdot e}= 2^e.$$

Comment: Why $(2^e)^e = 2^e??$ Please give me some reference.

Comment: @Arup, $e$ infinite $\implies$ $e\cdot e = e$ (AC required).

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla If $e$ is an ordinal, no choice is required.